# Update displayName while signup Firebase Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I want the app to save the `displayName` while user signing up

I've tried:

```
  Future<void> signUp() async {
    try {
      FirebaseUser user = (await FirebaseAuth.instance
              .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                  email: email.text, password: password.text))
          .user;
      UserUpdateInfo userUpdateInfo = new UserUpdateInfo();
      userUpdateInfo.displayName = name.text;
      await user.reload();
      showInSnackBar("User name ${user.displayName}");

      try {
        await user.sendEmailVerification();
        showInSnackBar("Email verification sent");
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      String errorCode = e.code;
      print(e);
      if (errorCode == "ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE") {
        showInSnackBar("This email is already in use");
      } else {
        showInSnackBar("Somthing went wrong! Try again later");
      }
    }
  }
```

with this method, `SnakBar` returns a null for `displayName`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `userUpdateInfo.displayName = name.text` isn't enough to actually change the name on the user account.  You have to call [updateProfile()](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseUser/updateProfile.html) and pass it that [UserUpdateInfo](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/UserUpdateInfo-class.html) object in order to actually change the account.

```
await user.updateProfile(userUpdateInfo)
```